# Angular: How can I optimize performance in a large-scale Angular application with complex data flows and frequent updates?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a large-scale Angular application that handles complex data flows and experiences frequent updates. As the application has grown, I've noticed a significant decrease in performance, especially when dealing with data manipulation and rendering.

I've already implemented basic performance optimizations like lazy loading modules, component change detection strategy tweaking, and OnPush change detection. However, I feel that there is much more to be done to improve the overall performance.

Considering the complexity of the data flows and frequent updates in my application, I'm looking for advanced techniques, strategies, and best practices to further optimize its performance.

Could someone with expertise in Angular and performance optimization share their insights and recommendations? Specifically, I'm interested in approaches for optimizing data handling, reducing rendering bottlenecks, managing large data sets efficiently, and improving the responsiveness of the application.

Lazy loading modules: I implemented lazy loading to load modules on-demand, expecting reduced initial load time and improved overall performance. The goal was to load only the required modules when navigating to specific routes. Component change detection strategy tweaking: I modified the change detection strategy to OnPush for components, aiming to reduce unnecessary change detection cycles and improve performance by triggering updates only when necessary.

Comment: hello. perfomance is a complex topics and you've already mentioned all the popular optimization related techniques that do exist. Many cases require exact debugging and resolving. I would include [rx-angular](https://www.rx-angular.io/) into the list of usual things that you could try to use. it should improve for example long lists rendering

Answer (score 1):

Other optimizations include

- Reducing the HTML content : simplify your HTML so that the engine has to render less. For instance :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You're looking at 7 HTML elements. If you use grid based layout :

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Now you have 5 HTML elements. Do this everywhere you can, and you should see some differences in performance.

- Loop tracking

`*ngFor` directives accept a tracking function

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of items; trackBy: tracker">
```

```js
tracker(index: number, item: any) {
  return index;
}
```

The tracking function is used to detect if the HTML element should be re-used or re-rendered. Try using it so that it gets re-used.

- Using containers, conditions and templates

Use `ng-container` for your structural directives (ngIf, ngFor, ngSwitch ...) because they do not generate HTML at runtime. Use `ng-template` and `*ngIf` to lazy load parts of your application to reduce the total of HTML elements, like the first point.

- State management optimization

You're probably using some sort of state management in your application. Let's assume it is RxJS-based. Use operators like `distinctUntilChanged`, `filter`, `throttleTime`, `debounceTime`, etc. to reduce the amount of triggers, so that your logic gets called less often.

- Memory leaks

Try finding memory leaks in your application. Those are usually created from observables that are not properly handled, and remain open even though they're not in use anymore. This takes up memory space and can bloat your application.

- Algorithm optimization

Try reducing your algorithm complexity to its maximum, and use web workers to reduce the load on the main thread.

- Reuse memory references

When dealing with large chunks of data (arrays of objects mainly), try to re-use the objects in the array instead of re-creating them. The garbage collector of Chrome will try to remove short-lived objects very often and you can loose a lot of processing power because of that.

Those are some of the optimizations you can do already, there's probably more but it's usually what I inspect first when dealing with performance issues.